# Mat button is focused after closing Material Sidenav

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

How to unfocus the mat button automatically after sidenav is closed.

[image]

```
<mat-drawer-container>
  <mat-drawer #drawer mode="over" position="end">I'm a drawer</mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content>
          <button mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()">
            <span class="material-icons-outlined"> shopping_bag </span>
          </button>
  </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I like this solution: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11403#issuecomment-390335586

> It can be solved pretty easily by adding onclick="this.blur()" to the button,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem aswell. I fixed it with adding following in my styles.scss:

 `.mat-button-focus-overlay { background-color: transparent !important; // needed for header menu }`